# python - open and write all files in dir

Tags: python

I have the following script that does multiple operations for .txt file (splits by tag, removes line breaks, sentence per line & blank lines in between).

I know how to do this for a specific file:

```py
import re

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    i = 1
    w = None
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            if w is not None and line == "</div>":
                w.close()
                i += 1
                w = None
            else:
                if w is None:
                    w = open('output_%i.txt' % i, 'w')
                for s in re.split("(?<=[.!:;?])\s+", line):
                    w.write(s + '\n\n')
```

How can I apply this to all .txt files in a dir?
I cannot figure out how to open and write to all files in a dir.

I thought this would work:

```py
import os
import re

path = "/Users/simon/dic/en-new-oxford/output"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r') as f:
        i = 1
        w = None
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                if w is not None and line == "</d:entry>":
                    w.close()
                    i += 1
                    w = None
                else:
                    if w is None:
                        w = open(os.path.join('path, filename_%i.txt') % i, 'w')
                    for s in re.split("(?<=[.!:;?])\s+", line):
                        w.write(s + '\n\n')
```

What is wrong about this?

Answer (score 0):

This does work. You probably had some other directory in your directory messing up your code.Also checks if the file ends with '.txt' .

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

path = ''
# Get all Files in directory , not other directory's.
allFiles = [join(path, file) for file in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, file)) and file.endswith('.txt')]
for file in allFiles:
    with open(file) as f:
        "do stuff here"
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the `w = open(os.path.join('path, filename_%i.txt') % i, 'w')` line works. It writes only into one file (`path, filename_1`). How can I specify the write part for each file?

Comment: You cant write to all files directly, you do it one by one. Thats why you get all files and do it in a for loop for each file.